# Debian web server doesnt work from ipv6 network

Tags: debian, ipv6, apache2

I need my website to be reachable from ipv6 for my ios app to be validated by apple. It was the case as I've been able to submit the first version of my app after following several tutorial to configure ipv6 but for some reason the server seems no more compatible with ipv6, and I don't find the problem.
The domain is creforma.fr

Maybe it can help:

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:07:cb:03:ae:e9
          inet addr:163.xxx.29.247  Bcast:163.172.29.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2001:xxx:2427:100::/56 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::207:cbff:fe03:aee9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6493973 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:1 frame:0
          TX packets:6107939 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:862938890 (822.9 MiB)  TX bytes:7704140929 (7.1 GiB)
          Memory:80000000-8001ffff

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1794 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1794 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:951370 (929.0 KiB)  TX bytes:951370 (929.0 KiB)
```

ping -c 1 localhost:

```
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms

--- localhost ping statistics --- 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev =
0.033/0.033/0.033/0.000 ms
```

ping6 -c 1 ip6-localhost:

```
PING ip6-localhost(localhost) 56 data bytes 64 bytes from localhost: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms

--- ip6-localhost ping statistics --- 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev =
0.030/0.030/0.030/0.000 ms
```

ping -c 1 ipv4.google.com:

```
PING ipv4.l.google.com (216.58.204.238) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from par21s06-in-f238.1e100.net (216.58.204.238): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=0.779 ms

--- ipv4.l.google.com ping statistics --- 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev =
0.779/0.779/0.779/0.000 ms
```

ping6 -c 1 ipv6.google.com:

```
PING ipv6.google.com(par21s06-in-x0e.1e100.net) 56 data bytes From par21s06-in-x0e.1e100.net icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable

--- ipv6.google.com ping statistics --- 1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

netstat -rn6:

```
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
::1/128                        ::                         U    256 0     0 lo
2001:xxx:2427:100::/56         ::                         U    256 0     1 eth0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
::/0                           2001:xxx:2427:1ff:ff:ff:ff:ff UG   1024 0     0 eth0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1    24 lo
::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   1   228 lo
2001:xxx:2427:100::/128        ::                         Un   0   1    54 lo
fe80::207:cbff:fe03:aee9/128   ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1    24 lo
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: After a scan on www.ipv6scanner.com all ports are filtered for ipv6 is it the firewall ?

Comment: And you do have `Listen [fe80::207:cbff:fe03:aee9]:80` in Apache's configuration?

Comment: I have `Listen [::]:80`

Comment: Listening on the link-local address doesn't make sense I this case. Listening on `[::]:80` is correct.

Comment: What information did your provider give you about the IPv6 configuration?

Comment: `/56` is not the proper length for a link prefix. It probably should have been a `/64`. Maybe the `/56` is a routed prefix and maybe the correct `/64` link prefix which is outside of your routed prefix. Try running `tcpdump -pni eth0 ip6` on the server while you ping it from a host with working IPv6.

Comment: @SanderSteffann my provider gives a /48 and optionnal /56 (with DUID)...

Comment: @kasperd tcpdump doesn't seem to receive anything when pinging from my windows pc in ipv6...

Comment: So your provider gave you a prefix of IPv6 addresses. As stated above each network should be a /64. You should ask your ISP how the prefix is routed to your server.

Comment: @Entretoize Duh. There wasn't supposed to be a `-p` option in that command. Does it produce anything if you type `tcpdump -ni eth0 ip6`?

Comment: It produce some results but don't seem to come from the ping... on ipv6scanner.com all port appears still filtered, how to be sure it's not simply a firewall ?

Comment: Any packet not generated by the host itself is relevant, even if it wasn't the packet you sent. When a packet originates from the outside the router will send a neighbor discovery packet. That neighbor discovery packet can provide much information about how the network is configured.

Answer (score 0):

First step you have to check your default route `netstat -rn6` and try to ping them

Comment: I added the result of netstat -rn6 command to my post, how can I know which is the default ?

Comment: Destination is `::/0` or `default` 
`::/0                           2001:bc8:2427:1ff:ff:ff:ff:ff UG   1024 0     0 eth0`

Comment: So... it doesn't ping the default route

Comment: What @Sander Steffann says ask you ISP about configuration. You can also try autoconfiguration. Check that you have enable `net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf` and `net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra` in `sysctl` and disabled `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding`. Then put `iface eth0 inet6 auto` in your `/etc/network/interfaces` and bring up interface

Comment: `iface eth0 inet6 auto` killed the whole connection...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Online hosting provider, did you carefully follow their tutorial: https://documentation.online.net/en/dedicated-server/network/ipv6/prefix ?

If not, you will have problems and any misconfiguration may trigger a protection on their network that will shutdown all your traffic, and you will need to contact their support team to lift it.

Comment: Yes, everything is well configured and it worked and without changing anything it stopped working. I have sshguard installed but even deactivating ip6tables the way described here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-iptables-stop/ the ports still seems filtered.

Comment: Then start from scratch, without `sshguard` and `ip6tables` and see if things work by just following the Online documentation.